# Respond with script from a Rails API app with limited middleware (config.api_only = true)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, middleware, respond-to, respond-with

I have a Rails 5 app build as an [api app](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html). So by default it only responds with json.

But for one specific request I need the app to respond with a script.

In a regular Rails app I would simply put my script in a `js.erb` file. This won't work here.

If my controller action looks like this:

```
def respond_with_js
end
```

and I request the app like this:

```
$.getScript("https://myapp.example.com/respond_with_js");
```

it responds with `204 No Content`:

```
Started GET "/respond_with_js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-27 20:28:44 +0200
Processing by ApplicationController#respond_with_js as */*
Completed 204 No Content in 0ms
```

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot request as script, if rails server is only api version.

Rails by default responds json.

```
def respond_with_json
   render json: {message: "works"}, status: :ok
end
```

To request it, you need to request as json dataType:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://myapp.example.com/respond_with_json",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res){
       console.log(res.message)
    }
})
```